# recursive repeat tree structure in Aurelia should work like accordion [Aurelia]

Tags: aurelia

I need some tree structure in Aurelia. I got some link for that. It's working fine. But My requirement is like accordion with tree view. Means when I  clicked on closed parent all opened parents should close and clicked one should open same as bootstrap accordion. same thing should happen When ever I clicked on child parent element with in parent repeat.

Below is my image for tree structure.
[image]

Gist run Link: **[Gist](https://gist.run/?id=53dc5b81ef1549cdcc56c3b1fa1e67ba)**

The above gist is just tree structure with open and collapse. From that when I clicked on closed tree node , that should open and remaining tree nodes should be closed.

In the above gist "node-model.js" is having events for open and close. So when ever I clicked on icon the clicked event inside this variable will get only clicked node. How can I get other node in that method to hide.

Comment: I think the solution to this would become a lot more apparent with some rethinking of the data structures you are using. For example, instead of using a `toggleNode` function, have a property that determines if a node's children are visible. Then you can just set one node's children to be visible and all others to not be visible.

Comment: @AshleyGrant: Problem is I was not able to figure out how to access the other nodes when I click on first node inside of node-model.js file. Can you help me how to do. `toggleNode(){
    for(var i = 0; i < this.children.length; i++){
      this.children[i].visible = !this.children[i].visible;
      if (this.expanded) { 
      this.children[i].toggleNode();
    }
    }
    this.expanded = !this.expanded;
    
  }` Here this is always showing as current node. How can I get other nodes from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer:**

Inside your `tree-view.js`, add the following code (3 methods):

```
  attached() {
    window.addEventListener('goCollapseAll', (e) => {
      this.closeOtherBranches(e.detail);
    }, false);
  }
  closeOtherBranches(exceptNode) {
    // traverse node tree to find current one
    var found = null;
    for(var i = 0; i < this.nodes.length; i++){
      if (this.subSearch(this.nodes[i], exceptNode)) { 
        found = i;
      }
    }
    if (found !== null) {
      for(var i = 0; i < this.nodes.length; i++){
        if ((i != found) && (this.nodes[i].expanded)) {
          this.nodes[i].toggleNode();
        }
      }
    }

  }
  subSearch(node, findNode) {
    // recursive search of tree for findNode
    var match = null;
    if (node === findNode) {
      match = node;
    } else {
      for(var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++){
        if (node.children[i] === findNode) { 
          match = node;
        } else {
          match = this.subSearch(node.children[i], findNode);
        }
      }
    }
    return match;
  }
```

Then, inside your `node-model.js`, add the following lines at the beginning of `toggleNode()`:

```
// close other node branches
if (!this.expanded) {
  var event = new CustomEvent('goCollapseAll', { 'detail': this });
  window.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

**Explanation:**

When a node is expanded, it publishes a custom event to trigger the recursive search to close all nodes that are part of a different branch.  It's not the prettiest solution and I think there might be a cleaner way if you adopt a different structure for the tree, but this solution definitely works well and accomplishes your purpose.

**GistRun:**

I've updated your GistRun to demonstrate the functionality.  You can see it working here:

https://gist.run/?id=828c3c79bff0dfbaffec3252ed376c8c

Comment: Hi may be there is a little bit confusion on my question. My requirement is like this: There is **Vallabha and Lstarky tree parent nodes**. Let assume **Vallabha tree node is opened and LStarky tree node is closed**. Now when I  click the Icon related to LStarky tree node , Vallabha tree Node should collapse and LStarky tree node should open. I updated Gist with Names of tree nodes. Can u please Update on same. Thanks n advance .

Comment: Okay, are you saying any time you OPEN a node you want all siblings nodes to close?

Comment: While doing like you mentioned, I was getting error was "closeOtherBranches not a function".

Comment: While doing like you mentioned, I was getting error was "closeOtherBranches not a function". Also I was unable to inject in node-model.js file. reason was to inject I need pass argument in constructor then that will have issue with bindable arguments to loop.

Comment: Thank you so much.